# $X\thicksim$ Cauchy$(\theta, a=1) \Longrightarrow \theta \equiv \mbox{ mode } \equiv \mbox{ median }$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable, $X\thicksim$ Cauchy$(\theta, a=1)$ where $\theta$ is not known. $X$'s PDF is:
$$f(x; \theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot \frac{1}{1+(x-\theta)^2}$$
I want to prove that $\theta$ is the same as the mode and the median of $X$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspection, $f$ is maximal at $\theta$ (so $\theta$ is the mode) and even in $x-\theta$ (so $\theta$ is the median).